# Не работает микрофон в Debian

Tags: unix, администрирование, аудио, debian, linux

Уже гуглил, находил много тем, но предложенные решения мне не помогли, а в некоторых просто не разобрался.

Микрофон не работает ни в скайпе, ни в `audacity`. Список устройств, которые можно выбрать в скайпе постоянно меняется (непонятно почему). Иногда при записи в `audacity` записывается шум (но чаще всего ничего не записывается).

Скриншоты из `alsamixer` и `kmix`:

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

В линуксе пару дней, так что даже не знаю, какую информацию представить :)

```
artyom@localhost:~$ lspci | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
01:00.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc RV710/730

artyom@localhost:~$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC262
Codec: Conexant ID 2c06
```

Comment: @ghost rider, я тоже так подумал, но:
"Если ваш вопрос относится к конкретным инструментам программирования (языки, среды, ...) (операционные системы, пакеты программ, ...), то ХэшКод - это удачное место, чтобы задать ваш вопрос." http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading7

"Если ваш вопрос относится к серверам, сетям, рабочим станциям, то РутКод - это удачное место, чтобы задать ваш вопрос."
http://admin.hashcode.ru/faq/#heading1

Термин "операционные системы" больше всего подходит к данной проблеме ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помогло

```
echo "options snd_hda_intel model=auto" >> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

с последующей перезагрузкой. В kmix'е появилась галочка захват у capture, которой раньше не было. Голочку снял и заработало.